# I'm writing an if/else statement in python(v 3.5.2) and need one of the actions to be to continue executing the program

Tags: python, tkinter

Example

```
if input1 is None:
    messagebox("Error", "No data was entered")
else:
    #code to continue program
```

Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: Er, there is no "code to tell the program to continue running". If you don't have anything you want to do in an else clause, don't have one.

Comment: Ok thanks for the help, is there any alternative you can think of to produce similar results?

Comment: @DanielRoseman yes but what that implies is that OP needs a way for the program to not continue to the next step when the input is empty.

Comment: @dylanr It might be helpful if you add to your question the code surrounding this if statement or an explaination of what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to not give out a messagebox, if the input is given, right? Then you can simply not write the else-clause. Now if the if-condition is not met, the program will just continue running without executing the code of the if-clause.

Answer (score 0):

```
while True:  # loop will run until break
    input1 = # get the input however
    if input1 is None:
        messagebox("Error", "No data was entered")
    else:
        break  # end the loop

# program continues here after loop ends with break
```

Comment: Thanks very much, helped me a lot and made me realise i was just over complicating things.

Comment: an infinite loop in a GUI is a bad idea, as it blocks the main event loop (`mainloop`).